# Swing GUI components too tighly packed

Tags: java, swing, layout, padding, margins

In the Java Swing app I made it seems to me that all the component are too tightly packed.

In QT one can specify padding and margins for the layout.

Is there something similar for swing?

[alt text http://img12.yfrog.com/img12/9612/screenshotscreenerconfi.png](http://img12.yfrog.com/img12/9612/screenshotscreenerconfi.png)

Here is a screen shot of my application that I thing is too tight (is it? what do you think?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the  [GridBagLayoutManager](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html). Its the most compex layout manager but everything can be acomplished whith it.

It uses the [GridBagConstraintObject](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) which has the inset property, it specifies the separation to the top, bottom, left and right components.

example: GridBagConstraintObject.insets.left=20

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) as your layout manager. It allows all kinds of customizations, including margins/paddings.

Comment: Thanks that could be an even better solution but currently I am reluctant to add another dependency to the project.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve a much better layout for the example above by using [DesignGridLayout](http://designgridlayout.dev.java.net/) in just a couple of lines of code (one per row in your layout). DesignGridLayout will automatically use the correct spacing for the runtime platform.

besides I would highly suggest that you DON'T use TitledBorders in your form because it prevents ANY LayoutManager (as advanced as it may be) from automatically aligning correctly the various components across different groups. Instead you could use a JLabel with a JSeparator (there are examples in DesignGridLayout, but this works with any other LayoutManager).

Comment: oh, so this is how you solve the V align issue, great thanks.

About the DesignGridLayout as I said: I am reluctant to add another dependency to the project.

Comment: no problem with that! But you should be aware that working with "pure" Swing (without ANY 3rd-party library, not just for layout, but also for tables, special widgets...) is a big pain! Your choice anyway;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 1.6 swing there is a new [GroupLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) manager that make this kind of works easier.

For instance there is a method: [setAutoCreateGaps()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html#setAutoCreateGaps%28boolean%29) that:

> *...you add two components to a SequentialGroup a gap between the two components is automatically be created...*

For instance:

[image]

Comment: That group layout seems great, I will give it a try.
Does by using GroupLayout, the user must have at least Java 6 runtime?

Comment: That's correct 1.6 is needed. I think if the user has < 1.6 you could take the source code of GroupLayout and ship it with your app. It is open source after all.  I like this better than GridbagLayout because you don't need all those gridbagcontraints objects :)

Answer (score 0):

What [LayoutManager](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) are you using? Adding margins is quite easy, it depends however on the specific LayoutManager used.

Comment: It is a vertical BoxLayout with horizontal Box(es).

Answer (score 0):

[FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/index.html) is another good layout manager. With a good GUI editor like [JFormDesigner](http://www.jformdesigner.com/) it makes GUI building easy enough. JFormDesigner actually automatically adds sufficient padding in most cases. I have to recommend against using GridBagLayout. It does the job alright, but is very complex which makes it difficult to use and maintain.

Comment: maybe, but I write open source and JFormDesigner is not free. maybe for others...